# Python regex how to insert hyphen symbol between an alphabet and a digit; and also remove hyphen in between two alphabets

Tags: python, regex, hyphenation

I am trying to use regex to do the following in a string :

- If there is a hyphen `-` between two alphabets, we have to remove it:

  - **Example** `A-BA` should be `ABA`; and `A-B-BAB` should be `ABBAB`
- If an alphabet and a number are next to each other, then we have to insert a hyphen `-` symbol between them:

  - **Example** `9AHYA7` should be `9-AHYA-7`; and `977AB99T5` should be `977-AB-99-T-5`

These patterns are just simple examples. The string could be more complicated like this :

- `HS98743YVJUHGF78BF8HH3JHFC83438VUN5498FCNG`
- `7267-VHSBVH8737HHC8C-HYHFWYFHH-7Y84743YR8437G`

In the above strings the same principles have to be incorporated.

I tried the following code to convert `8T` into `8-T`

```
    re.sub(r'\dab-d', '\d-ab-d', s)
```

Unfortunately it does not work. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: "The alphabets and numbers in the string could be different" to what extend can you add examples?

Comment: Elaborated more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use 2 capturing groups with lookarounds and in the replacement  use a lambda to check which group matched.

If group 1 matched, remove the last character. If group 2 matched, append a hyphen.

```
([A-Z]-(?=[A-Z]))|([A-Z](?=[0-9])|[0-9](?=[A-Z]))
```

*Explanation*

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]-(?=[A-Z])` Match A-Z and - and assert what is on the right is A-Z
- `)` Close group
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[A-Z](?=[0-9])` Match A-Z and assert what is on the right is a digit
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9](?=[A-Z])` Match 0-9 and assert what is on the right is A-Z
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g0RDW7/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UPNSR2)

*Example code*

```
import re

pattern = r"([A-Z]-(?=[A-Z]))|([A-Z](?=[0-9])|[0-9](?=[A-Z]))"
strings = [
    "A-BA",
    "A-B-BAB",
    "9AHYA7",
    "977AB99T5",
    "HS98743YVJUHGF78BF8HH3JHFC83438VUN5498FCNG",
    "7267-VHSBVH8737HHC8C-HYHFWYFHH-7Y84743YR8437G"
]

for str in strings:
    result = re.sub(
        pattern,
        lambda x: x.group(1)[:-1] if x.group(1) else x.group(2) + "-",
        str
    )
    print(result)
```

*Output*

```
ABA
ABBAB
9-AHYA-7
977-AB-99-T-5
HS-98743-YVJUHGF-78-BF-8-HH-3-JHFC-83438-VUN-5498-FCNG
7267-VHSBVH-8737-HHC-8-CHYHFWYFHH-7-Y-84743-YR-8437-G
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `re.sub`, then here is one way, using capture groups:

```
inp = "8T-ENI-A2"
output = re.sub(r'^(.)(.)-([^-]+)-(.)(.)$', '\\1-\\2\\3\\4-\\5', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
8-TENIA-2
```